# How to find variable equation solution

Tags: linear-algebra, recreational-mathematics

[My adopted method to find solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmfTY.jpg)

\begin{align}
&\frac{-4x + 40}{x-7} &=& \frac{4x-40}{13 - x}\\
\implies& \frac{-(4x - 40)}{x-7} &=& \frac{4x - 40}{13 - x}\\
\implies& \frac{-(4x - 40)}{x-7}\times \frac{1}{4x - 40} &=& \frac{4x - 40}{13 - x} \times \frac{1}{4x - 40}\\
\implies& \frac{-1}{x - 7} &=& \frac{1}{13 - x} \\
\implies& \frac{-1}{x-7} &=& \frac{1}{13 - x}\\
\implies& x - 13 &=& x - 7
\end{align}

Please tell me what basic mathematics rule I violated to get such a wrong answer .
PS I know how the right solution , I just need to know what is wrong with my current method .

Comment: Welcome. Please type up your question and explain your motivations and workings. That being said, please notice that you can only divide by $4x-40$ if —— (what kind of division breaks a mathematical rule, as you put it?)

Comment: Note that a solution is $x=10$.

Comment: You can't divide by $\frac{1}{4x-40}$ because it can equal $0$ and Robert pointed out that $10$ is a solution so $\frac{1}{4x-40} = \frac{1}{4\cdot 10 - 40} = \frac{1}{0}$

Comment: So , everytime I try to remove a common numerator witha  variable , I have to make sure it's value may not be equal to zero .

Answer (score 1):

You have made one mistake:

- You have divided both sides by $4x-40$ but you first have to check if $4x-40$ is equal to $0$ or not. So first let take $4x-40=0 \implies x=10$. We notice $x=10$ is fulfiling the original equation.

Special point:

- You have got $\dfrac{-1}{x-7}=\dfrac{1}{13-x} \implies x-13=x-7$. Since this equation has no possible solution the only solution is the first point answer or $x=10$